# Plist NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:] source path is nil'

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsfilemanager, info.plist

Trying to **create plist file**.
but Gets error in 
**[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil**

do someone know why it's happening?
Thank you very much..

**AppDelegate.h** :

```
NSError*error;
NSArray*pathes=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString*documentDirectory=[pathes objectAtIndex:0];//first dir in app dir.
NSString*path=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

NSFileManager*filemanager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![filemanager fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    NSString*bundle=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];//check if plist file exist;



    [filemanager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
    NSMutableDictionary*data=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray*arr=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    [data setObject:arr forKey:@"arr"];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`- [NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` returns `nil` if the requested file is nonexistent. Make sure that the app bundle really contains `data.plist`.

Comment: And `-pathForResource:ofType:` does *not* search recursively, so make sure you're pointing to the right directory that contains your plist.

Comment: this code is not supposed to create the Plist file ?
can you direct me to the "App Bundle" ?

Comment: @Ofir_Tel.Aviv Neither of these two sentences is meaningful/makes sense. I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: the problem is
when the app lunches, it's crashes, and present the above error message..

because plist bundle error,
but the code seems OK

Comment: the App dictionary is not appear on the path !
Library -> application support -> iPhone Simulator -> 5.1(and any simulators) -> Applications -> [app folder] -> Documents

Comment: @Ofir_Tel.Aviv But that's precisely what I am talking about. You can't copy the file from a location where it isn't.

Comment: @Ofir it is, but the source file can't be nil even then (read the error message). You can't copy a nonexistent file.